# How can I fix the attribute error: module 'noisereduce' has no attribute 'reduce_noise'

Tags: python, noise-reduction

I have run the code below and it keeps on giving me the attribute error;

```
import noisereduce as nr
from scipy.io import wavfile
from noisereduce import reduce_n

# load data
rate, data = wavfile.read("output.wav")
# select section of data that is noise
noisy_part = data[10000:15000]
# perform noise reduction
reduced_noise = nr.reduce_noise(audio_clip=data, noise_clip=noisy_part, verbose=True)
```

It gives the attribute error below

```
AttributeError: module 'noisereduce' has no attribute 'reduce_noise'
```

Comment: if your file name is "noisereduce.py" the code will import himself and raise this problem

Comment: ohhh thanks alot, it has been fixed

Comment: good pls add my answer as usefull

Comment: @eyal You didn't post an *answer*.

Answer (score 1):

This was because I saved the code as noisereduce.py, it there for imported itself  when i ran the code and since there is no named attribute called reduce_noise, I got that error.
Thanks alot  @Eyal